# Basic relations in django (built on top of a legacy db)

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've googled on and on, and I just don't seem to get it.

How do I recreate simple join queries in django?

in models.py (Fylker is county, Dagensrepresentanter is persons)

```
class Fylker(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    navn = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.navn
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'fylker'

class Dagensrepresentanter(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=33, primary_key=True)
    etternavn = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    fornavn = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    fylke = models.ForeignKey(Fylker, db_column='id')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.fornavn, self.etternavn)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['etternavn']  # sette default ordering
        db_table = u'dagensrepresentanter'
```

Since the models are auto-created by django, I have added the ForeignKey and tried to connect it to the county. The id fields are inherited from the db I'm trying to integrate into this django project.

By querying

```
Dagensrepresentanter.objects.all()
```

I get all the people, but without their county.
By querying

```
Dagensrepresentanter.objects.all().select_related()
```

I get a join on Dagensrepresentanter.id and Fylker.id, but I want thet join to be on fylke, aka

```
SELECT * FROM dagensrepresentanter d , fylker f WHERE d.fylke = f.id
```

This way I'd get the county name (Fylke navn) in the same resultset as all the persons.

Additional request:
I've read over the django docs and quite a few questions here at stackoverflow, but I can't seem to get my head around this ORM thing. It's the queries that hurt. Do you have any good resources (blogposts with experiences/explanations, etc.) for people accustomed to think of databases as an SQL-thing, that needs to start thinking in django ORM terms?

Comment: Have you been using [`./manage.py inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb)? - it could help you deal with legacy database.

Comment: ./manage.py inspectdb shows me the starting point of my models.py file. e.g the `fylke = models.ForeignKey(Fylker, db_column='id')` from my current models.py is represented as `fylke = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)`. What do I learn from that? That django haven't noticed that I have changed the models.py? Or?

Comment: @Eriks: What do you really want to achieve? Do you want your database to follow changes from the models? Use South. Do you want the models based on what you have in the database? Use `inspectdb`. Do you want to just create database from scratch based on models? Define models and use `syncdb`. I do not know where is the problem. If you want to learn ORM, there are plenty of tutorials and ORM is just an abstraction layer on top of the database (Object-Relational Mapper is pretty descriptive name).

Comment: I ideally want to build a django app on top of a legacy db (in the term from the django docs: http://tinyurl.com/89pvvj5). But doing this, as the doc says using `inspectdb`relatons are lost (no fields gets `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField`, `OneToOneField`), and I do not understand how to tell django how to add a `... WHERE a.field = b.field` in a `Model.obcjects()`-type query.
I'd be rather puzzled if I'm the only one that have had problem this, and ask for tutorials covering this problem from a SQL-type angle for people used to this kind of thinking.

Comment: @Eriks: Do you really have foreign keys in your database? I bet not. If I am right, first use inspectdb, then use South to create initial migration, change proper fields int foreign keys / relation fields, then create another auto migration with South and then apply it. You should have updated database structure after this process.

Answer (score 0):

Your legacy database may not have foreign key constraints (for example, if it is using MyISAM then foreign keys aren't even supported).

You have two choices:

1. Add foreign key constraints to your tables (would involve upgrading to Innodb if you are on MyISAM).  Then run ./manage inspectdb again and the relationships should appear.
2. Use the tables as is (i.e., with no explicit relationships between them) and compose queries manually (e.g., Mytable.objects.get(other_table_id=23)) either at the object level or through writing your own SQL queries.  Either way, you lose much of the benefit of python's ORM query language.